# Unable to connect to server: connection to server failed: timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUWTy.jpg)

Ｉset publicly accessible is true,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFg9W.jpg)

also add inbound rule below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1rAO.jpg)

This is my first time using Amazon RDS on EC2, and I already try myself two days. thanks!